# jQuery-prototype conflict: table filter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been at this one for a while now:

I'm using both jQuery and Prototype within Redmine, a RoR webapp. They play along well thanks to jQuery's noConflict.

I've got jqGrid working fine too.

Now here's my problem: I'm trying to use the [Table Filter plugin by PicNet](http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet_table_filter.html)
but I get the following js error:

> this.each is not a function

@ line 862 of prototype.js

```
function collect(iterator, context) {
   iterator = iterator || Prototype.K;
   var results = [];
   this.each(function(value, index) {
      results.push(iterator.call(context, value, index));
   });
   return results;
}
```

It's obviously calling a prototype function while it should not, but the plugin code is minimized, and actually compiled with python, so there's no un-minimized version...

I'm not very good with js to start with, and I'm stumped as to why it calls the wrong function...

P.S: I'm using

- jQuery 1.4.4
- Prototype 1.7
- Firebug 1.8.4 for debugging

Update: found the answer myself, see below!

Comment: Hmm.. I'm new here. Is it normal for stackoverflow to remove my civilities?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures perhaps.

Comment: @illiptic - yeah - things like "Thanks in advance" or "any help would be..." are usually removed as noise.

Comment: I think the problem is that the "collect" function itself is, for some reason, being called such that `this` is not an Array instance.

Comment: @Pointy: yeah, as I said, the jQuery plugin is calling a Prototype function, which is puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the 'closure' lib, a dependency for Table Filter:

```
 /**
  * @define {boolean} NATIVE_ARRAY_PROTOTYPES indicates whether the code should
  * rely on Array.prototype functions, if available.
  *
  * The Array.prototype functions can be defined by external libraries like
  * Prototype and setting this flag to false forces closure to use its own
  * goog.array implementation.
  *
  * If your javascript can be loaded by a third party site and you are wary about
  * relying on the prototype functions, specify
  * "--define goog.NATIVE_ARRAY_PROTOTYPES=false" to the JSCompiler.
  */
```

So I downloaded the necessary things (python, closure compiler, ... ) and built the Table Filter code myself with this parameter set to false, and it works.

Now I've got another problem, but I should be ok. If not I'll come back here and ask!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap the plugin in:

```
;(function($) {
    // This way you secure that $ in this local scope is referring to jQuery and not prototype.
    // Original plugin goes here....
})(jQuery);
```